# Swift embedded library -> Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, skmaps

I'm trying to integrate swift framework to my project:
http://developer.skobbler.com/download/SKMaps_iOS_2.4.0_withDemo_Swift.zip

When I try to integrate as embedded binary xcode couldn't code sign and tells me 
 "codesign failed with exit code 1".

```
CodeSign /Users/k1x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMaps-dubiwcafqgeplbabdrqpjtokouxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestMaps.app/Frameworks/SKMaps.framework
    cd "/Users/k1x/Workspace iOS/SwitchMaps"
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 56131F60BE8DA3BA4F04CBF6717C75951E93E4D6 --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules /Users/k1x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMaps-dubiwcafqgeplbabdrqpjtokouxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestMaps.app/Frameworks/SKMaps.framework

Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
/Users/k1x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMaps-dubiwcafqgeplbabdrqpjtokouxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestMaps.app/Frameworks/SKMaps.framework: invalid resource specification rule(s)
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

And I tried to put the framework in "Linked frameworks and binaries section". But I've got following output:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SKMaps.framework/SKMaps
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B3686F36-2120-4007-97AB-B2D3B423C0A0/TestMaps.app/TestMaps
  Reason: image not found
```

I googled and found another posts for this issue but they didn't answer my question. 
Just in case everything works correct with Objective C version of it:
http://developer.skobbler.com/download/SKMaps_iOS_2.4.0_withDemo.zip

Comment: We are looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use cocoapods for install it.

I had the same problem, I like this and it worked.

Edit : With cocoa pods, you need to add a line containing pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK' to your Podfile, run pod install in the Terminal and import the SKMaps/SKMaps.h header in order to use the library or import the SKMaps/SKMaps.h header to your Objective-C bridging header if you are using Swift.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include a summary of the solution at the linked article?

Answer (score 0):

Select the SKMaps.framework from the Frameworks folder and uncheck and then check back the SKMapsSwiftDemo target (in Target Membership) as shown in [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z94488n4x26h7xh/FixSwiftIssue.png?dl=0).

This will not be necessary in the next version of the SDK.

Comment: I use XCode 6.3 and I unchecked and checked back the checkmark, the issue still remains.

Comment: Devs will investigate it asap

Comment: As Apple is updating Swift constantly, these kind of bugs  will most likely happen also in the future. 
One solution you could try: call super.init(nibName: nil, ) in custom initializers. For example, in GPSFilesViewControler, init(fileName: String) I called super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) instead if super.init().  Check also for other solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031270/initializer-does-not-override-a-designated-initializer-from-its-superclass

Comment: @SergeySurkov a solution from our devs: For dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SKMaps.framework/SKMaps error please select your target, go to General tab then go to embedded binaries section and add SKMaps.framework. 
For the codesign error go to Build Phases add SKMaps.framework and check the Code Sign On Copy option.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SKMaps.framework/SKMapsReferenced from:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/
B3686F36-2120-4007-97ABB2D3B423C0A0/TestMaps.app/TestMaps
Reason: image not found
```

I faced the very same problem (Swift project from scratch.)

Adding *SKMaps.framework* under **Embedded Binaries** (*Project / Target / General / Embedded Binaries*) did the trick here:

[image: Embedded Binaries]

Clean, build, run.