# Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, initializer

So I've just upgraded to Xcode 6.3 Beta 3 and a lot of error(s) are appearing relating to the following:

> Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass.

```
override init() {
    super.init()
}
```

For example this is a `UIButton` class:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var target: AnyObject!
    var selector: Selector!
    var action: (() -> Void)!

    override init() { // Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass
        super.init() // Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIButton'
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

This is one of my `UIViewController` classes:

```
class CustomAlertView: UIViewController {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    required override init() { // Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass
        super.init() // Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

My solution is a quick fix, but I think is easier than what Apple purposes on the the Release Notes. For more information search for 19775924 http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta_3/Xcode_6.3_beta_3_Release_Notes.pdf here. What Apple says is that you create an Objective-C file and extend it (having to add it to the header files and all) and it's on "Known Issues in Xcode 6.3 beta 3", so I think is easy to do what I did:

This is how I fixed it for `UIButton`:

```
class CustomButton : UIButton {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And this is one of my ViewControllers (remove public if not needed):

```
public class GenericViewController: UIViewController {
    public init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I don't use IB so I also have `UIView`, because I do separate the view from the `viewController` (remove public if not needed):

```
public class GenericMenuView: UIView {
    public init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I need this specially in views because I have a `setupViews` method that I override in all subclasses that is called on the init. And using AutoLayout I don't need any frames (so I don't override the init with the frame parameter).

So it seems you have to drop `override`. Oh! and be sure to not call `self.init()` or the class is never initialized (and it crashes after some internal timeout).

Answer (score 8):

As per Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222), what you are overriding is a convenience initializer. So for your initializer to work, you will have to change the method to

```
override convenience init() {
    super.init()
}
```

You can either do that, or remove the initializer if you are not really using it except for calling the superclass initializer.

Answer (score 3):

I recently figured this out and I'd like to explain what the problem was. Originally answered on the [Apple Developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1112998#1112998).

It seems Swift has changed the strategy for initializer dependency checking or for imporing initializers.

Now if your initializers' are as shown, one way to deal with both Xcode 6.3 Beta 2 and Beta 3 is to remove all initializer definitions:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var target: AnyObject!
    var selector: Selector!
    var action: (() -> Void)!    
}

class CustomAlertView: UIViewController {

}
```

Without defining any designated initializers, classes inherit all initializers of their superclasses.

A pretty easy fix, but a big gotcha that had me stumped for a while.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is way easier than it seems.

For an SKSpriteNode, I was doing this:

```
override init() {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bgTile")
    super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: texture.size())
}
```

The problem is init() is not the designated initializer for SKSpriteNode.  So I just changed it to:

```
override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: UIColor!, size: CGSize) {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bgTile")
    super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: texture.size())
}
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Error : Override init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) not working like expected - Swift

This works for me , Try this, Note: u must awake nib

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

     super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialisation code

}
```