# SKMaps.framework: code object is not signed at all

Tags: ios, skmaps

> .Frameworks/SKMaps.framework: invalid resource specification rule(s)
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
>   The error is related to: code object is not signed at all.

The same error occurs with Swift SKMapsSwiftDemo. I'm using Xcode 6.3, OS X 10.10.3 and iOS 8.3, but I tried Xcode 6.1, OS X 10.9.5 and iOS 8.1.3 too.

Adding script as `--deep` doesn't resolve the issue. Code Sign On Copy activated for SKMaps.framework destination Frameworks.
How may I resolve the issue?

Comment: Do the steps at http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood help you ?

Comment: Try to select the SKMaps.framework from the Frameworks folder and uncheck and then check back the SKMapsSwiftDemo target (in Target Membership).

If this doesn't solves the issue you could check other suggestions related to swift issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031270/initializer-does-not-override-a-designated-initializer-from-its-superclass”

Apple is updating Swift constantly and these kind of bugs will most likely happen constantly.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering, I can't comment yet. I'm getting the same error in my project since I cannot install SKMaps from Cocoapods with Swift frameworks mixed.
Installing the framework manually as they tell in their webpage throws the same error:

```
/Users/Gabri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HolaSwift-bwlblhyipzsnozbxivjiuizsnrjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/E-Bike.app/Frameworks/SKMaps.framework: invalid resource specification rule(s)
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have to say that this error is only thrown when building the app to a real iOS device, not in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by installing this library with Cocoapods with pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK' and then import SKMaps/SKMaps.h header to my Objective-C bridging header.

Hope it helps