# Xcode 7.3.1 Swift "initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass" error

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class HGHero: SKSpriteNode {

var body: SKSpriteNode!
var arm: SKSpriteNode!
var leftFoot: SKSpriteNode!
var rightFoot: SKSpriteNode!
```

The error comes here:

```
override init () {
```

I'm not sure what's going on. I'm trying to override the default init for SKSpriteNode.

```
super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blackColor(), size:    
CGSizeMake(32,44))
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Comment: If you search Google with that you'll find dozens of questions already asked on SO. Do more research. Possible duplicate of [Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031270/initializer-does-not-override-a-designated-initializer-from-its-superclass)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `override` keyword.

```
class HGHero: SKSpriteNode {

    var body: SKSpriteNode!
    var arm: SKSpriteNode!
    var leftFoot: SKSpriteNode!
    var rightFoot: SKSpriteNode!

    init() {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blackColor(), size:
            CGSizeMake(32,44))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }   
}
```

> Infact initializers are not inherited (like instead happen with methods or properties). So you do not override them.

### Just a note

These implicit unwrapped optionals

```
var body: SKSpriteNode!
var arm: SKSpriteNode!
var leftFoot: SKSpriteNode!
var rightFoot: SKSpriteNode!
```

are very dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the help, appzYourLife!